# Keeping older data on partition hive table

Tags: hive

Keep history data onto a partitioned table

Team,

I have scenario here - I have 2 tables - one is non partitioned and another one is partitioned table partition on one date field.

Have loaded the data from non-partitioned tables to a partitioned table and I have set the below parameter to  load onto partition table.

```
write.partitionBy(“date”) \
.format(“orc”) \
.mode(“overwrite”) \
.saveAsTable(“schema.table1”)
```

Now both table count match which has 3 years of data. Which is as expected.

now I have refreshed only latest one year of data and try to load the partitioned table but it got loaded only with 1 year data, where as I need all 3 years data in the partitioned table.

What am I missing here.. I have to refresh only 1 year of data and load it to the partition table and keep building history.

Kindly suggest. Thanks

```
write.partitionBy(“date”)
.format(“orc”)
.mode(“overwrite”)
.saveAsTable(“schema.table1”)
```

Need to keep history with latest data refresh on each day basis.

Comment: I went further ahead and did below - df.write.insertInto("schema.table1",overwrite = True).format("orc").partitionBy("date") but now I getting below error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partitionBy' . Any thoughts.

Comment: Anyone has any thoughts??